# Magento Extends CartController and Add new PostAction

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I extended the controller CartController and I added a post action

```
class Zap_PayFee_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
    {

        public function indexAction() {
            Mage::log('IndexAction');
            parent::indexAction();
        }

        public function estimatePayFeePostAction()
        {
            Mage::log('Estimate Payfee Action Post');
        }
    }
```

my config.xml

```
...
    <frontend>
        <routers>
             <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <zap_payfee before="Mage_Checkout">Zap_PayFee_Checkout</zap_payfee>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    ......
    <global>
        <rewrite>
                <zap_payfee_checkout_cart>
                    <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>  
                    <to>/payfee/checkout_cart/</to>
                </zap_payfee_checkout_cart>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
...
```

payfee.phtml

```
<form id="payfee-cart" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePayFeePostAction') ?>">
    <fieldset>
    <?php foreach($methods as $method =>$type):?>

        <input type="radio" name="payfee" value="<?php echo $type['value'];?>"><?php echo $type['label'];?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button"
                        title="<?php echo $this->__('Get PayFee') ?>"
                        onclick="coPayFeeMethodForm.submit()"
                        class="button">
                        <span><span>
                        <?php echo $this->__('Get PayFee') ?>

                    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

the indexAction () works while estimatePayFeePostAction ()
does not work

what is my url address ? action= getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePayFeePostAction')

Comment: In your controller did you add `<?php  require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'CartController.php'; class Zap_PayFee_Checkout ... and geturl should be `Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePayFeePost')`

Comment: Also if you use `before="Mage_Checkout"` then you dont need `<from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>  
                    <to>/payfee/checkout_cart/</to>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not required to add 'action' when using getUrl

```
$action = Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePayFeePost');
```

Should return the currect url.